# Hide shortcuts in Dash Home on Unity

Tags: unity, unity-dash, shortcuts

In *Unity 2d* you can hide the **Shortcuts** section of the **Dash Home**

However in *Unity* I cannot hide this.. I do see a 'minimize' icon in the top corner after I open **Dash Home**

[image: Shortcuts]

<sub>Clicking on **Shortcuts** does nothing.</sub>

I do notice clicking on the minimize icon repeatedly does make it appear darker (the white is whiter :P) however the button does not serve a function.

[image: minimize first view]

<sub>*Click once*</sub>

[image: minimize first click]

<sub>*Click twice*</sub>

[image: minimize second click]

<sub>*Click three times*</sub>

[image: minimize third click]

<sub>*Keep going and it gets a bit whiter*</sub>

Is this button *supposed* to control this action? or is this a separate bug?

**Update:** I realize the minimize button does not control this action, with that said. Is there a way to hide the 'shortcuts' section of the Dash Home and just display the 'search'  (+results once a search term is entered)?

Comment: I have since created this [question](https://answers.launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/+question/184284)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would support your "bug" theory.

However, according to [Ayantana Design](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/838875), the minimise/maximise buttons now work as expected:

```
Desired solution:
- When the Dash in windowed:
--- 'Close' window decoration closes the Dash
--- 'Minimise' window decoration is inactive (does nothing)
--- 'Maximise' window decoration makes the Dash full screen

- When the Dash in full screen:
--- 'Close' window decoration closes the Dash
--- 'Minimise' window decoration is inactive (does nothing)
--- 'Restore' window decoration returns the Dash to windowed state
```

As to the "increasing brightness" issue - if you take the above as the expected result - your observation could be classified as a bug - albeit relatively cosmetic.

Comment: ok, so if that is by design. is there a way to hide the 'shortcuts' like in Unity 2d?

Comment: someone has filed just this request on the one-hundred papercuts project.  Perhaps you could add your support to that report? https://bugs.launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/+bug/912467

Answer (score 1):

The brightness change is indeed a bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/871327